# PHP eliminate array element based on selected element from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have these arrays:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)

$b = array(2,3);

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
)
```

I want to eliminate elements from array `$a` which is contained in array `$b`. So the result will be like:

```
$c = array(1,4,5,6,7);

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 7
)
```

is there any PHP Functions to do this? thank you

Comment: You're looking for [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff):

```
$result = array_diff($a, $b);
```

Test:

```
print_r(array_diff([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [2,3]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try array_diff() funciton

$c = array_diff($a, $b);
```